# Disable syntax highlighting in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, syntax

Sorry for an obvious one, but I'm using Texmaker as my editor and the syntax highlighting has broken down after adding a `tikzpicture` and is making it very hard to actually see the content. (Everything is green as if it were mathematical notation). Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Comment: thanks @texenthusiast if you convert that to an answer I'd be happy to upvote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open TeXmaker File menu --> Options-->Configure-->Editor--> Colors and change according to your liking based on [color codes](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm). Just for update: [TeXmaker 4.0.1 dated March 16 2013](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) is available now